# Correct way to define module for RequireJS with AMD?

Tags: requirejs, amd

I'm trying to move over to using just plain old **vanilla JS** in my project. I've always been a bit of a jQuery fan, but I've noticed how much slower it is compared to to native JS; and this project is speed sensative, so I need to squeeze everything I can out of the design.

I've got **RequireJS** setup. I have a pretty simple setup:

```
// Configure loading modules from the lib directory,
// except 'app' ones,
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../app",
      "spots": "spots",
      "booking": "booking",
      "markup": "markup.min",
      "cat-filters": "cat-filters",
      "common-functions": "common-functions",
      "categories": "categories",
      "domReady": "domready",
      "css-map": "../../maps/jquery.cssmap2"
    },
    "shim": {
        "common-functions": {
            "deps": ["domReady"]
        },
        "categories": {
            "deps": ["common-functions"]
        }
    }

});

if (window.VARS.thisPage == "home") {

    require(['domReady','common-functions','css-map'], function(domReady){


    }, function (err) {
      console.log("Error: " + err)
    });


}
```

Then in the (for example), spots.js, I have:

```
(function(factory){
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["jquery"], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function($, undefined){

   // module code here

}));
```

This works fine with jQuery. However, without it I never get the code triggered. I have tried removing the wrapper code from the module - and while it seems to run, I get an error in the console:

```
Error: Error: Load timeout for modules: common-functions,cat-filters,categories
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!